# Delete cookies in cherrypy

Tags: cookies, cherrypy

I am trying to delete or expire cookies in Cherrypy, but it does not seem to be working. this is how I try:

```
cookie[mykey]['expires'] = 0
cherrypy.request.cookie.clear()
```

After executing these lines of code, I still can see cookies and read them

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to official [cherrypy document](https://cherrypy.readthedocs.org/en/3.2.6/progguide/cookies.html), in order to expire cookies in cherrypy, we need to re-create them in **response** and set expiry date and max-age

```
    cherrypy.response.cookie[key] = ''
    cherrypy.response.cookie[key]['expires'] = 0
    cherrypy.response.cookie[key]['max-age'] = 0
```

I was altering cherrypy.request.cookie which will not have any effect on the cookies.